# Pass buffer as argument to function

Tags: c

I want to pass a buffer as argument to a function and use it somewhere else afterwards. I've tried different ways:

```c
void parseData(uint8_t Data);
void parseData(uint8_t *Data);
void parseData(uint8_t Data[]);
```

and then called the function to use it

```c
data_result[10U]={1,2,3,...,10};
parseData(data_result);
```

but none of them worked.

Comment: The second and third declaration for `parseData` are equivalent. Both take a `Data*`.

Comment: `parseData(uint8_t* address_of_first_element, size_t number_of_elements)` as the function, and `parseData(data_result, 10)` at the call site. The techniques available to you in C and C++ differ.

Comment: `void parseData(uint8_t *Data)` and `void parseData(uint8_t Data[])` will both work, but you need to call the function like `parseData(data_result)`. Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: "but none of them worked." How?

Comment: `parseData(uint8_t data_result);` is a hint to either get a good book, or stop skipping whole sections in the one you have. that error is pretty fundamental.

Comment: Is the buffer size implicitly known? Otherwise you prbably need a size parameter.

Comment: Depending on how exactly it fails, you might want a few `;`.

Comment: @Yunnosch No, I guess that was a typo.

Comment: Guessing is one thing, a proper [mre] prevent the need for guessing.

Comment: @WhozCraig it was just a fault when typing the question and i modifyed it

Comment: @Yunnosch That was obvious. The question is more about which declaration is the correct one.

Comment: Please, instead of adding details mentioned in comments, make a MRE ( [mre] ). That prevents you missing some details, even if they are already mentioned in comments or answers. (I guess that one of the answers below becomes unnecessary once you show your actual code. Which in turn means your edit makes this a moving target question, unfairly making the answer look inapplicable. So please, for now or at least the future, learn to make a MRE, it is also a great way of debugging.)

Comment: _it didn't work_ is never a sufficiently detailed description of what happened when you attempted to do somthing.  Give the expected results vs actual results and include the exact text of any error messages you encountered.  It seems like maybe you just need to pass a _size_ argument.  Perhaps you assumed the size would be passed implicitly somehow?  (array size is *not* passed implicitly - you have to manually pass the size as an additional parameter)

Comment: I suggest declaring the function as `void parseData(uint8_t Data[static 10]);` to indicate that pointer `Data` must point to a buffer with at least 10 valid bytes

Answer (score 3):

The function call syntax as well as the declaration for `data_result` is incorrect. The correct syntax would be as shown below:

```
void parseData(uint8_t *Data)
{
    
}
int main()
{
//--vvvvvvv------------------------------->added type of element of the array
    uint8_t data_result[4]={1,2,3,10};
//------------v--------------------------->removed uint8_t from here 
    parseData(data_result);
    
}
```

You can also pass the size of the array as the second argument as shown below:

```
//-----------------------------------vvvvvvvvv--->second parameter is size of array
void parseData(uint8_t *Data, size_t arraySize)
{
    
}
int main()
{
    uint8_t data_result[4]={1,2,3,10};
//-------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv------->pass size of array as second argument
    parseData(data_result, sizeof(data_result)/sizeof(data_result[0]));
    
}
```

Comment: Judging by the name of the function, I think is appropriate to pass the size of the array too.

Comment: @alex01011 Doing that is trivial. Also, none of the function declaration shown above has a second parameter taking the size of the array.

Comment: @AnoopRana  yes exactly i didn't need the size inside the function but i used like x=Data[5U]; to use x after

Comment: @lb01 Ok that's what i suspected. In that case, you can use the 1st version given in my answer which has no second parameter corresponding to the size of the array.

Comment: @lb01 Also, i would suggest that in your question you should add whatever error you're getting. Just try out your original code [here online](https://onlinegdb.com/L-PM4OSMy) and then copy/paste the error that you get to your original question so that the question becomes more clear and concise.

Comment: the problem is it dosen't show any error it works fine but it  dose not print this function results as if it dose not exist

Comment: @lb01 Can you share a link to the demo so that we can see for ourselves what is happening and why there is no error. [Here](https://onlinegdb.com/L-PM4OSMy) there is an option to shared the link. You can share that link here. First you have to click on *Fork* and they type your code and then finally click on share.

Comment: It can just be 4, doesn't have to be 4U

Comment: @user253751 Yes, i didn't bother to remove that `U`, but now that you've mentioned it i did remove it.

Comment: `unsigned int` could be a narrowing conversion. What's your objection to using `size_t`?

Comment: @Bathsheba I did originally used `std::size_t` but then someone removed the `c++` tag and i changed it to `unsigned int`. See the edit history of my answer. Now that you've mentioned it, i have changed it back again to `size_t` without the `std::` ofcourse.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forgot to define `data_result` properly. The type is missing.

`uint8_t data_result[10U]={1,2,3,---,10}` might work.

But it would be great if you give more information about what is not working, like a compiler error.